# R programming: cache the inverse of a matrix

Tags: r, caching, closures

I am following a Data Science course on Coursera and I have a question regarding one of the assignments where I have to inverse a Matrix and then cache that result.

Basically I have been googling away and I found the answer but there are parts of the answer that I do not yet understand. For this reason I don't want to submit my assignment yet since I don't want to submit anything that I do not fully understand.

The part that I do not understand from the code below is the part where setInverse is defined. where does the 'function(inverse) inv' come from? especially the 'inverse' was never defined?

After this a list is returned which does not make much sense to me as well?

If someone could take the time to explain this function to me I would be very grateful!

```
    makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
    inv <- NULL
    set <- function(y) {
        x <<- y
        inv <<- NULL
    }
    get <- function() x
    setInverse <- function(inverse) inv <<- inverse
    getInverse <- function() inv
    list(set = set,
         get = get,
         setInverse = setInverse,
         getInverse = getInverse)
}


## Write a short comment describing this function

cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
    ## Return a matrix that is the inverse of 'x'
    inv <- x$getInverse()
    if (!is.null(inv)) {
        message("getting cached data")
        return(inv)
    }
    mat <- x$get()
    inv <- solve(mat, ...)
    x$setInverse(inv)
    inv
}
```

Comment: If you need to just invert a matrix, `solve` is the function you have to use (see the changes to your function in @Roland answer). So, if `a` is a matrix, just `b<-solve(a)` will get the inverse matrix of `a`. Don't really get what the code above has to do with inverting a matrix.

Comment: I've edited my code. Basically the first function is used to perform a 'cache' function. Then the second function uses 'solve' to calculate the inverse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know your exact assignment, but I would change your function slightly:

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
  inv <- NULL
  set <- function(y) {
    x <<- y
    inv <<- NULL
  }
  get <- function() x
  setInverse <- function() inv <<- solve(x) #calculate the inverse
  getInverse <- function() inv
  list(set = set,
       get = get,
       setInverse = setInverse,
       getInverse = getInverse)
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
funs <- makeCacheMatrix()
funs$set(matrix(1:4, 2))
funs$get()
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
funs$setInverse()
funs$getInverse()
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   -2  1.5
#[2,]    1 -0.5
```

The exercise is probably intended to teach you [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures). The point is that `x` and `inv` are stored in the enclosing environment of the `set`, `get`, `setInverse`, `getInverse` functions. That means the environment within which they were defined, i.e., the environment created by the `makeCacheMatrix()` call. See this:

```
ls(environment(funs$set))
#[1] "get"        "getInverse" "inv"        "set"        "setInverse" "x"
```

As you see not only are the four functions in this environment, but also the `x` and `inv` objects (a consequence of using `<<-`). And the `get` and `getInverse` functions only fetch these from their enclosing environment.

Comment: If you are right and the lecture was about closures and not about inverting a matrix in R, you are a clairvoyant! +1, very nice explanation of closures.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just edited my code and you can see the entire assignment now. The first function was to learn about 'caching' while the second function was to demonstrate inversing and the fact that when you cache you can save computingpower.

On top of that it seems logic that I also learned about closures here!

What I still don't understand though is how 'inverse' can be used in my code while it wasn't ever declared before? Is this because of the '<<-' operator?

Comment: After Googling I now know what you mean! Thank you for answering my question! :)